# Do I need to emit watermark even if I am not processing anything in flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading from one stream and writing to another stream. My code just looks like this

```
env.addSource(source).addSink(sink)
```

do I need to still emit watermark ?

Answer (score 2):

No, You don't. As long as You are not doing any processing that uses event time, then You don't need to emit watermarks.